# Rich snippets won't show? Local business

Tags: seo, google-search-console, html, google-search, rich-snippets

I have been trying to get Rich snippets to show on my website for months now with no prevail. A week or two ago the ratings were showing up in SERPS on all pages (except homepage which isn't marked up), but after another week went by they disappeared again with no apparent reason? I checked to see if the code had been changed or was out of date but it still says its working with no errors when tested through google's tester.

This is the code that I am using:

```
    <div id='rs_container' itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<p>
<span itemprop="name" id='rs_companyName'>Vital Parts ltd</span>

<span itemprop="aggregateRating" id='rs_rating' itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    is rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.65</span> stars by Reviews.co.uk based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">26</span> merchant reviews
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what is going on? I have tried everything now and really need a fresh perspective on the whole thing!

Answer (score 1):

The code seems in order. 
But one of the guidelines for use of AggregateRating
"Make sure the reviews and ratings you mark up are readily available to users from the marked-up page. It should be immediately obvious to users that the page has review or ratings content."
Reviews, I suppose, aren't present on the website. And I am guessing that you don't link to your profile on Reviews.co.uk.
So I suggest to try that - to link to your page on Reviews.co.uk, where this reviews are present